# CMake define preprocessor macros used by all source files for each executable

Tags: c++, c, cmake, organization

I am working on a C++ multi-file project. I decided to use CMake to build the project (I am beginner with it). I have the following (simplified) file structure:

```
my_project/
├─ src/
│  ├─ foo/
│  │  ├─ foo.cpp
│  │  ├─ foo.hpp
│  ├─ baz/
│  │  ├─ baz.cpp
│  │  ├─ baz.hpp
│  ├─ main.hpp
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ app/
│  ├─ scenario1/
│  │  ├─ scenario1.cpp
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ scenario2/
│  │  ├─ scenario2.cpp
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
```

My source files all use on C preprocessor macros all defined in the main.hpp file. I would like to define different values of these macros for `scenario1.cpp` and `scenario2.cpp`.

---

### Example

I tried with a minimal example to achieve this goal:

#### main.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef MAIN_HPP
#define MAIN_HPP

#include <iostream>

#ifndef SCENARIO_VERSION
#define SCENARIO_VERSION 0
#endif

#endif // MAIN_HPP
```

#### foo.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

#include "main.hpp"

#if SCENARIO_VERSION == 1
void foo(int);
#elif SCENARIO_VERSION == 2
int foo();
#else
void foo();
#endif

#endif // FOO_HPP
```

#### foo.cpp

```cpp
#include "foo.hpp"

#if SCENARIO_VERSION == 1
void foo(int a)
{
    std::cout << "(foo) Version 1\n"; 
}
#elif SCENARIO_VERSION == 2
int foo()
{
    std::cout << "(foo) Version 2\n"; 
    return 0;
}
#else
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "(foo) Version DEFAULT\n"; 
}
#endif
```

#### scenario1.cpp

```cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
#include "baz.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Scenario version = " << SCENARIO_VERSION << '\n';

    baz(0);
    foo(0);

    return 0;
}
```

#### my_project/src/foo/CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
set(HEADER_LIST "${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.hpp" "${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/src/foo/foo.hpp")

add_library(foo SHARED foo.cpp ${HEADER_LIST})

target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC . ..)
```

#### my_project/app/scenario1/CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
set(HEADER_LIST "${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/src/baz/baz.hpp" "${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/src/foo/foo.hpp")

set(SCENARIO_VERSION 1)

add_executable(scenario1 scenario1.cpp ${HEADER_LIST})

target_link_libraries(scenario1 PRIVATE baz foo)

target_include_directories(scenario1 PRIVATE "${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/src/baz" "${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/src/foo")

target_compile_definitions(scenario1 PRIVATE SCENARIO_VERSION=${SCENARIO_VERSION})
```

When I try to build (`cmake --build build`) my project, there are problem of reference (none of the definition of `foo()` is working (either `foo(0)` (scenario 1) or `foo()` (default) )).

Note : when i remove the line `target_compile_definitions(scenario1 PRIVATE SCENARIO_VERSION=${SCENARIO_VERSION})`my_project/app/scenario1/CMakeLists.txt, it compiles and run (though it uses default value of SCENARIO_VERSION)

---

### Assumptions so far

I am pretty sure it is due to some circular linking or something similar.
I am also aware that `target_compile_definitions(scenario1 PRIVATE SCENARIO_VERSION=${SCENARIO_VERSION})` it is not supposed to change the value of `SCENARIO_VERSION` for `foo` and `baz` targets, as they don't depends on `scenario1` or `scenario2` targets.

I also tried to use INTERFACE library for `foo` and `baz` without too much hope, but it didn't work.

I saw posts with questions similar to mine, but it didn't seems to work in my case (or at least I didn't succeed):

- [How can I build two executables that share a main function in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70919957/how-can-i-build-two-executables-that-share-a-main-function-in-cmake)
- [Cmake configuration to build same source with different options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222379/cmake-configuration-to-build-same-source-with-different-options)
- [cmake: Building multiple versions of a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278930/cmake-building-multiple-versions-of-a-program)
- [CMake : different configure_file() for each target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836470/cmake-different-configure-file-for-each-target)

I guess I have to build the libraries for each scenarios as the code is supposed to be different for each scenario, but I don't see a way to do this properly (and according to the modern CMake standards ([Effective Modern CMake](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1#file-effective_modern_cmake-md))).

Comment: Do you build the `foo` library with the define?

Comment: What do you mean ? Which define ? I don't understand.
Normally the foo library is always built.

Comment: You build your application with the macro `SCENARIO_VERSION` defined to a specific value. But the `foo` function is defined in the `foo` library, which is a separate and distinct entity from the `scenario1` target and application. When `scenario1` and its sources are being built, the `foo` library will already have been built, without the macro defined, and you can't change what's already built for that library.

Comment: Yes, that's actually my problem : is there a way to build those libraries for each executable ? Is there a way to automate that ? Is there some trick to avoid writing the code for each scenario ?

Comment: In your top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file, use `add_definition` to add macros to be used by all targets. Then when you build the libraries should have that macro defined as well.